# Handle NULL and with Value (comma Separated) Parameters in where condition in SP

Tags: sql-server

Based on this ulr https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/06/18/write-case-statement-clause-interview-question-week-127/

I wrote

```
SubRegionCode =
                CASE WHEN (@SubRegionCode IS NOT NULL AND @SubRegionCode != '') THEN @SubRegionCode
                ELSE SubRegionCode END
```

And based on this article

[https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-all-records-when-Parameter-is-Blank-Empty-or-Null-in-SQL-Server-Query.aspx#:~:text=Inside%20the%20stored%20procedure%2C%20the,the%20table%20will%20be%20returned](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-all-records-when-Parameter-is-Blank-Empty-or-Null-in-SQL-Server-Query.aspx#:%7E:text=Inside%20the%20stored%20procedure%2C%20the,the%20table%20will%20be%20returned).

```
(SubRegionCode=@SubRegionCode or ISNULL(@SubRegionCode,'')='')
```

Both are working if I have values like `@SubRegionCode=N'EURA'` and `@SubRegionCode=N''`, but result is coming as 0 (not working) if I have values as `@SubRegionCode=N'EURA,US'`.  That is if we pass 2 values from FE, its not working.

Comment: Do you have any rows where the value of `SubRegionCode` is `N'EURA,US'`? If not, then that's why. If you do, however, you should be fixing your design and not storing delimited data.

Comment: If, however, you are under the impression that `SubRegionCode = N'EURA,US'` would be parsed as `SubRegionCode IN (N'EURA',N'US')` then you're understanding is wrong. You will likely be better off with a table type parameter here.

Comment: If you're passing delimeted data in a string then that's a poor design and you'll need to parse it out into rows to work with it as a `set`. Post some sample data and your full relevant query.

Comment: I have achieved, this see the below url for more details https://forums.asp.net/p/2175797/6337334.aspx?Re+Handle+NULL+and+with+Value+comma+Separated+Parameters+in+where+condition+in+SP